# Antivirus integration in PHP

Tags: php, integration, antivirus

I want to integrate antivirus plugin in my code ( To check the files when users are uploading or downloading, Like yahoo mail). How do we integrate an antivirus component inside PHP? Any ideas or help would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you have Anti-Virus software running on your web server that you can interface through the command line? This is not going to be a trivial task.

Comment: @pekka, I need to integrate one. Which would be best pick for integration?

Comment: @Dinzy I don't know, but you'll probably need to provide more info to have a chance to get an answer: What operating system you are on, what kinds of files you are planning to scan, what kind of budget you have....

Comment: Im on Windows Platform, Files includes everything from pictures,Zipped files,Text files etc

Comment: @Dinzy You may have to work through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_antivirus_software and see which ones can be used through the command line. As @Gordon says ClamAV seems to provide an interface and a PHP library, it may be worth a look

Comment: @Pekka, Thanks man. Im on it. Will try my best to Integrate AV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on which AV solution you are using. If there is no bindings for PHP for that particular solution, you have to see if you can trigger the av check through system or exec calls.

An example of an AV solution that actually does provide bindings for usage with PHP would be

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-clamav/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Which AV is easy and best for the integration?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try my best to integrate it.

Comment: php-clamav is GPL licensed... you should really think twice before integrating it with a proprietary piece of code.  Shameless plug but http://scanii.com is a much better (and risk free) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself an antivirus that is runable from the console, and use the [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function to execute it, analyse the returned output.